# How to run action on jQuery selected elements in certain order?

Tags: jquery, sorting, css-selectors

I have a HTML table like this:

```
<table>
 <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td class='latest order1'>X</td><td class='latest order4'>X</td></tr>
 <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td class='latest order3'>X</td><td class='latest order2'>X</td></tr>
 <tr><td>X</td><td>X</td><td class='latest order6'>X</td><td class='latest order5'>X</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, I want to run a jQuery action (an ajax call) on all objects of `latest` class, that's a simple:

```
$('.latest').each(do_call());
```

But since the ajax action takes some time, I have the elements ordered by their importance. And I would like to run the `do_call()` for object with `order1`, then for `order2` element, and so on.

How can I sort jQuery objects, so the actions would run in proper order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get all the `.latest` elements and their order classes in an array:

```
var order = [];

$('.latest').each(function() {
    // Get the order - all elements have class 'latest orderX':
    // remove the 'latest', get the classname, and add the latest back.
    order.push($(this).removeClass('latest').attr('class'));
    $(this).addClass('latest');
});
```

Then sort the array and loop through it, get the corresponding element:

```
order.sort();

for(var i in order) {
    var obj = $('.latest.'+order[i]);
    do_call(obj);
}
```

This method works even if your `.latest` elements are not sequentially indexed; eg. you can have `order4` after `order1` with no `order2` or `order3` present and it still works.

Comment: Why the `.attr('class')`? Is it necessary?

Comment: Well, yes, if you want to get the classname of the element.

Comment: Ok, but doesn't ´attr´ chained with ´addClass´ return a jQuery-object?

Comment: @Mickel, you're right, the addClass should be on it's own. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

this can probably be more efficient but it should do what you are looking for:

```
var latestItems = $('.latest');
var order = 1;
for(var i = -1, len = latestItems.length; ++i < len ) {
    var item = $('.latest .order' + order);
    doCall.call(item);
    order++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it all in one 'big' ajax call instead of running separate ajax calls for each element? Figure out a way to consolidate your data in such a way that it be separated on the server side and a have a single response update the elements on the client.

Comment: because if an ajax call takes ~30seconds to 5 minutes, I prefer doing it in smaller chunks - just to be able to update and display the result for most important parts faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find [AJAX QUEUE plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue) usefull. From the manual:

> Ajax Queue is a plugin that helps to manage Ajax race conditions. When multiple Ajax requests are made in rapid succession, the results can be returned out of order. This can cause weird behavior in your application. Ajax Queue is a plugin (actually, 2 plugins) that provide a way to manage these requests.